# React router v4 won't switch view

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

When I tried programmatically change view, it changes only url, not view.

What I have:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createHistory();
```

I bind click listener to some elem:

```
<div onClick={this.navigateMeToHome}>To Home</div>
```

And when I listen this:

```
navigateMeToHome = () => {
   history.push('/')
}
```

Url have changed to home url, but route view still same.

What is wrong and how can I solve this?

**UPD:
And this component outsite Switсh:**

```
<div>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
    <Header/> <=== This guy.
    <div className="container">
     <div className="app">
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" render={props => <Home {...props}/>}/>
       <Route path="/search" component={Search}/>
     </Switch>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

Comment: First, you do not need this in react-router v4: `import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'; const history = createHistory();`. Second, could you share the class/function where the `navigateMeToHome` resides in?

Comment: Yes, I know, I can navigate through this.props.history.push('/elsewhere').
The problem is my Menu class  is not Route component.

Comment: Could you share the code? If your class is not a Route component, you can use `withRouter()` to provide it with the same props that a Route component got.

Comment: withRouter is not solution, cuz I cant import {withRouter} in v4
here the code example if you need it:
https://gist.github.com/Nayami/c1fd3ed16ccacdff3e3d8263d4ddf81d

Comment: Why can't you import withRouter? In the `menu.jsx`, you can add `import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';` and modify `export default class Menu extends Component {}` to `class Menu extends Component {}; export default withRouter(Menu);`. Is that a problem?

Comment: because I got "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined" when I tried to bind this to menu : import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
withRouter(Menu)

Comment: Oh, nwm. There was a typo. withRouter(Menu) seems working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Three things I would look into first.

1. Are you simply *just* using ReactTraining/history? If so, that is just controlling the browser history. It's has no effect on the routing of components which would come in and out of view.
2. If you are utilizing a react-router, react-router-dom, etc. Ensure that your routes are nested inside of the  component provided by ReactTraining's router libraries. There are other ways to switch out view, but Switch is one of the simplest implementations.
3. Ensure you are storing the state of this transition somewhere. Reason being, if the state doesn't change, then the component holding the different views has no reason to trigger a re-render, placing the view you're looking to see in and out of the view.